# How to get current caller view page file in HTML helper extension method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper

I create HTML helper extension to combine script into one file like the following code. It will combine both jQuery and jQuery UI file into common.js file at specified location. I use ASP.NET caching with file dependency to monitor all combined files. If some file is changed, the method will re-generate combined file.

```
@(Html.CombinedFiles
(
    "~/Scripts/common.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"
))
```

Everything works perfectly. However, it has only one problem. When developer modify view page that call this function for adding or removing file to be combined. ASP.NET caching is still valid. Method will not re-generate combined file because I don't add caller view page to file dependency list.

I want to know. Is it possible to get view page to call this extension method? It must support both ASPX and Razor view engine.

**Thanks,**

PS. [Documentation](http://higgs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20-%20Combine%20Script) about this function in my [Higgs RIA framework](http://higgs.codeplex.com) for more understanding this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IView view = htmlHelper.ViewContext.View;
if (view is BuildManagerCompiledView)
{
    string viewUrl = ((BuildManagerCompiledView)view).ViewPath;
    // use viewUrl here    
}
```